# How to add client side validation in joomla frontend module with alert?

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, module

[image: This is a simple module]

This is a simple module I need a phone No. (format=+x-xxx-xxx-xxxx) and url validation. Validation show on top position and red color. This right side module and validation true field color green.

Comment: Try and google it, I know for a fact that google has a guide / tutorial on how to validate fields.

Comment: If you want to use the Joomla tel field type and also the tel rule that will help, but that assumes you will save in the standard y.xxxxxxxxxx format where y is country code. Joomla also has built in url validation if you use a url field.

Comment: Just cleaning up, but well asked over all